# apache mod_proxy www.domain.com fails, domain.com works - whats wrong?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have a apache setup that redirect to my app running on tomcat.  Loading http://domain.com works fine.  However http://www.domain.com gives me a 404 error.

What am I missing?

```
NameVirtualHost www.domain.com:80
<VirtualHost www.domain.com:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ProxyPass /svn !
    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/appname/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/appname/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /appname/
</VirtualHost>
```

Following the first comment I have altered by code to be:

```
<VirtualHost www.domain.com:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
    ProxyPass /svn !
    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/appname/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/appname/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /appname/
</VirtualHost>
```

In the apache logs I see a 404 error "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16060"
In the browser I see an apache tomcat 404 error (tomcat 6.0.28)
I see nothing in the tomcat logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#serveralias).

```
<VirtualHost www.domain.com:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
    ProxyPass /svn !
    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/appname/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/appname/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /appname/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:**
When facing that kind of problems, you can directly hit tomcat on its HTTP port (see server.xml) and check if the problem occurs.

Comment: tried this, however I still get the 404.

looking in more detail, it appears to get to the tomcat, and that is where the 404 occurs (based on the title of the error) will check the logs.

Comment: Then it's not an Apache problem.
Please edit your question with details regarding your application: application container, technology used, configuration...